# Downgrade open jdk 8 to 7 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8, java-7

I accidentally upgraded the whole system in ubuntu 14.04.

I am trying to deploy a war file which requires JDK7.

I tried to install JDK7 and use it as default

```
root:floyd~# update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

but it is not installing as well. It gives following error while trying to install JDK 7.

```
root@floyd:~# apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' has no installation candidate
```

I guess I have two options.

1. Install JDK7 and use it as default.
2. Downgrade JDK8 to JDK7.

I think downgrading can be a good option but I am not able to do any of them.

Comment: I recommend having a look at [jEnv](http://www.jenv.be/) which lets you easily switch between multiple Java installations.

Answer (score 13):

**Installing JRE/JDK in default configuration**
OpenJDK 7 is installed as default in Ubuntu 12.10 and later.
Installing Java whereby apt-get is easy:

```
sudo apt-get update

java -version
```

If after execution we have something like: "The program java can be found in the following packages", it means that Java isn't installed. So, we need to to:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

As result, `Java Runtime Environment (JRE)` will be installed. When we want to install `Java Development Kit (JDK)`, which is needed for compilling Java-app (for example, Apache Ant, Apache Maven, Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA) we need to do:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Now, Java is installed.

**Installing `OpenJDK 7` (optionally)**

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

After execution `Java Runtime Environment (JRE)` will be installed. For `Java Development Kit (JDK)`, we execute:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

---

**Installing Oracle JDK (optionally)**
Oracle JDK is an official JDK but, now, Oracle doesn't support it like default for installation in Ubuntu.

We can install it by apt-get but before we need to execute next commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Later, we have to choose needed version and execute:

For Oracle JDK 6

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

For Oracle JDK 7

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

For Oracle JDK 8

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

For Oracle JDK 9

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

**Managing of Java (optionally)**
When we have some version Java installed we can choose one of them as default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

As result we will see something like this:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1062      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1062      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

We can see it on the screen:
[image]

The same action we can do to choose the compiler (javac):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

This command can be used to choose other java componenst, for example, like: keytool, javadoc and jarsigner.

**Installing "JAVA_HOME"**
To be installed `**JAVA_HOME**`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Result like:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1062      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1062      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

As we can see the paths for java will be:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Now, we need to copy one of the ways and paste it into:
`/etc/environment`:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

In the file we are going to add a path(where YOUR_PATH - is path for desired version of java, for example: "`/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`"):

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"
```

On the screen:[image]

Now, we need to reboot this file:

```
source /etc/environment
```

To check it we can:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

On the screen:[image]

When we have, now, input way("/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle" in our example) it will be means we do it sucessfully. In other way we need to be more attentive and check all these steps once.

Comment: The link you've provided seems to be russian-only.

Comment: I was trying to make the information more comfortable. I think it can be helpful. Also, you can find more information here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

Comment: After a day of searching, I could not go for any one the options since there were multiple errors. So, used the backup to get app online.

 Maybe I will try above suggestion on another virtual server to see how it works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have checked it on own machine (ubuntu 16.10 and 17.10). It works fine.