# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade and Cassandra connection errors

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 17.xx to 18.04 and Cassandra somehow broke.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error Connection refused")})
```

I tried going through some setup steps again, but the cassandra user and group are there, as are the setup files.

```
sudo systemctl -l status cassandra
```

reports **active (exited)** with the last log being:

```
Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
```

**Update**:
I guess the log is pointing to this:

```
CassandraDaemon.java - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (...) or note tool (enablethrift) to start it
```

Running `nodetool` is also broken:

```
error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

with a `java -version` of 10, so I'm guessing that's the cause.

Knew I shouldn't have upgraded

Now looking for a way to change the JVM version Cassandra uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your issue is most likely because of your new Java version. Cassandra only supports Java 8 (or 7 for 2.2 and below). But there is no reason why you can't have two JDKs on your machine, so there is no reason to uninstall Java 10. This answer is a bit old but still relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118725/1516699

You can keep Java 10 as default if you want and set a specific version for Cassandra to use. To do this, edit the cassandra.in.sh file in your Cassandra bin directory. There is a line commented out where you can set JAVA_HOME.

Comment: I looked at that file yesterday, they must have removed JAVA_HOME from it in the latest version, but I will try to add it in and see what happens.

Comment: That does seem to work. JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64". I put it at the top of the file. You can have the points anyways :)

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked. This is what I meant btw: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/bin/cassandra.in.sh#L44